# Counting Correlated Query with Proc SQL

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have a table master_t with customer_id and product_id and flyer_section

[image: table screenshot]

I want to count how often "back" appears per customer_id, so far I have

```
proc sql
create table cust as
select
    distinct customer_id
    count((select(flyer_section from master_t where master_t.customer_id = distinct master_t.customer_id and flyer_section = 'back'))
from master_t
;
quit proc sql
```

I'm getting a syntax error, and I'm not sure if it will work anyways

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your query, shouldn't something like this work?

```
create table cust as
select
    customer_id
    count(flyer_section) as BackCount
from master_t
where upper(flyer_section) = 'BACK' 
      or lower(flyer_section) = 'front' 
      or lower(flyer_section) = 'inside'
group by customer_id
```

Comment: Sorry I should have said the reason I was trying to use a subquery was because I also wanted to count how often "front" appears and " inside" in the same table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy in SAS because of the way it evaluates boolean expressions.

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table cust as
    select customer_id
         , sum(upcase(flyer_section)='BACK') as n_back
         , sum(upcase(flyer_section)='FRONT') as n_front
    from master_t 
    group by 1
   ;
quit;
```

Of course why not just use

```
PROC FREQ ;
  tables customer_id*flyer_section / missing noprint out=counts ;
run;
```